# jquery draggable element no longer draggable after drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I want to be able to repeatedly drag and drop the same source element.

At the moment when an image is dragged, it is cloned successfully - that is the original image stays put and the clone drops nicely into its new place, but the old image is no longer draggable. Inspecting the element shows `class` as an attribute (no value) i.e. not `class="ui-draggable"`

As you'll see I've tried to re-enable draggability onto the original after the cloning, but its not working.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var copy = 0;
    var dragOptions = {
      helper: 'clone',
      cursor: 'hand',
      revert: 'invalid'
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("img").draggable(dragOptions);
      $("ul#bag > li").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
          copy++;
          var clone = $(ui.draggable).clone().attr("id", "img_" + copy);
          $(this).append(clone);
          clone.css("left", 0).css("top", 0);
          $(ui.draggable).draggable(dragOptions);
        }
      });
    });
</script>
  <style type="text/css">
    li
    {
      position: relative;
      float: left;
    }

    img
    {
      cursor: move;
    }

    div, li
    {
      display: block;
      width: 160px; 
      height: 123px;
      margin: 2px;
      border: solid 1px gray
    }

    .clear
    {
      clear: both;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <ul id="bag">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="shop">
    <li><img id="img1" src="images/p1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img id="img2" src="images/p2.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img id="img3" src="images/p3.jpg" /></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="clear" id="dustbin" style="background-color:Black;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, it appears that once the item is dragged, the draggable widget calls its own destroy() function which removes any semblance of draggability from the element.

With no discernible way of overriding this with options or events, I've overridden it with brute force in document.ready:

$.ui.draggable.prototype.destroy = function (ul, item) {  };

This now works.

Comment: This changed nothing for me, indeed some simple testing shows that the destroy method is never called on drop.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but wanted to provide another solution to those that need to keep the `.destroy` and would like to keep it the same name.

I made a function to apply the `draggable` state to an element...

```
function MakeDraggable(ele) {
    ele.draggable({ revert: "invalid" });
}
```

Then inside of the `drop` property of the `.droppable` elements I simply...

```
MakeDraggable(ui.draggable);
```

This re-enables the draggable state to the element.

Comment: Why would you not just add $(draggable).draggable(); inside your drop? This works the exact same as your solution but with a few less lines.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for figuring out a solution. However i really needed the destroy method... so after using your solution, i assigned the native destroy method to another method... so your solution with mine would be something like this;

```
$.ui.draggable.prototype.destroy = function (ul, item) { };
$.ui.draggable.prototype.remove = function() {
    if(!this.element.data('draggable')) return;
    this.element
        .removeData("draggable")
        .unbind(".draggable")
        .removeClass("ui-draggable"
            + " ui-draggable-dragging"
            + " ui-draggable-disabled");
    this._mouseDestroy();

    return this;
};
```